# Stoke's Theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was given a question in my multivariable calculus course regarding Stoke' Theorem. This is what it ask.

> > Find $\int_{\Gamma}\langle x^2,z^2,y^2\rangle \cdot d\vec{r}$ where $\Gamma$ is $x =\cos(t) , y = \sin(t), z = 3\sin(t)$ from $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$. Then check that it equals $\int\int_{\Sigma} \text{curl}\langle x^2,z^2,y^2\rangle \cdot d\vec{S}$ where $d\Sigma = \Gamma$.

This is my way of approaching the problem. First, define key components. 
On the curve, $\Gamma$ our curve is defined by $\vec{r} = \langle \cos t, \sin t, 3\sin t\rangle $. Thus are $d\vec{r} = \langle \text{-}\sin t, \cos t, 3\cos t\rangle dt$. As for $\vec{F}$, $\vec{F} = \langle \cos^2t, 9\sin^2t, \sin^2t\rangle $. When we evaluate the Line Integral, we get.

\begin{eqnarray}
 \int_{\Gamma}\vec{F}d\vec{r} & = & \int_0^{2\pi}\langle \cos^2t,9\sin^2t,\sin^2t\rangle\cdot\langle \text{-}\sin t,\cos t, 3\cos t\rangle dt\\
& = & \int_0^{2\pi}(\text{-}\cos^2tsin t + 9\sin^2t\cos t + 3\sin^2\cos t)dt \\
& = & \int_0^{2\pi}(\text{-}\cos^2tsin t + 12\sin^2t\cos t)dt\\
& = & \frac{\cos^3t}{3} + 4\sin^3t |_0^{2\pi} = 0
\end{eqnarray}

Now according to Stoke's Theorem:
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Gamma} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r} = \int\int_{\Sigma} \text{curl}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{S}
\end{equation}
The curl of $\vec{F}$ is $\langle \text{-}4\sin t, 0 ,0\rangle$. This is where I am stuck. I do not know what to have as $d\vec{S}$, nor am I sure what to have as my limits of integration. The answer should be zero by stoke's theorem but I need to check by actually evalulating. Any suggestions or comments on things I might have missed.

Thank you for your time and Thanks in advanced for any feedback you supply.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to figure out what the curve $\Gamma$ looks like, and what a reasonable choice of surface $\Sigma$ would be. Here's a large hint: $\Gamma$ is the intersection of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ and the plane $z=3y$. Draw a sketch (not necessarily a perfect one) and finish the problem.